# Is glass better than PMMA or PC at anti-fogging?

Tags: steam, glass

I think that the title says it all.

To give context, I have experimental hints that glass is performing less badly than PMMA or PC at anti-fogging but I have not been able to build a DIY experimental setup that un-ambiguously answers the question and I suspect that there is a lot more to this than what I know about it.

Google has taught me that considerable engineering and research ressources have been spent on designing surface treatments for PMMA and PC to improve their anti-fogging properties so, my question is more specifically focused on comparing uncoated glass to uncoated PMMA/PC.

I can give more context about why this question is interesting to me but I am not sure it will be useful to someone who attempts to answer it so, in the interest of brevity, I will leave this as-is for now.

Comment: What was your experimental setup? Did you control ambient temperature? did you control surface temperature? did you control relative humidity? What surface treatments did you test?

Comment: @SolarMike it's totally un-scientific but I have cut pmma and pc lenses for my diving mask, and have set one lens of each on the mask. Then, I put it on, waited until one of the two lenses shows fogging. Glass consistenly wins over PMMA and PC: it takes longer to fog.

Comment: I should add that the default lenses for my diving mask are made of glass and I am fairly certain this is uncoated glass because: 1. the mask is OLD so any coating is long gone) , and 2. I burned the glass lenses a long time ago to remove optical glue (yes, I had correction glass lenses glued to the original glass). So, what I am comparing is one lens made from glass, pc, or pmma against another one. I also tried multiple versions of pc and pmma.